# how do I split a numeric column into two separate columns in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I am trying to join two tables together but the key in one table is formated like 'xxxxxx' and the key I am trying to join together in the second table is formated like '2222xxxxxx'. Is there a way I can either split the second column into two different columns to make the join, or join on only the last 6 numbers of column 2?

Notes: values are numeric. the '2222' is always the same 4 numbers.

Comment: How are you trying that? Also, both in mysql AND Oracle?

Comment: You can use the modulo operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select * 
  from table1 a 
         INNER JOIN table2 b
                 on a.fieldname = substr(b.fieldname, -6)
```

Here is the documentation for the [SUBSTR Function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm) in Oracle.

Know that this is a very bad design for your second table you should consider in separating this values in different columns.

**EDIT**

This comment from @Boneist "if there were 7 numbers after the first 4, not just 6?"

To fix this you should use: `substr(b.fieldname, 5)`

To separate that column on a select statement either you create a new column and update it values with the given `substr` or just add it in the select command.

On the `select` command:

```
select fielda, fieldb, 
       substr(b.fieldname, 1, 4) firstPartOfField,
       substr(b.fieldname, 5) secondPartOfField
  from tableb
```

To create another column it would be

```
alter table tableb add column newField number(6);
update tableb 
   set oldField = substr(b.fieldname,1,4),
       newField = substr(b.fieldname,5);
```

Comment: My only reservation about this answer is what if there were 7 numbers after the first 4, not just 6? Wouldn't `substr(b.fieldname, 5)` be better, based on the OP's assertion that the first 4 numbers are always the same? Completely agree on the suggestion to permanently split the column into two!

Comment: You are right @Boneist I did this way because of the OP assertion `or join on only the last 6 numbers of column 2` I will add this information on my answer! Thanks.

Comment: You are both correct. Can I split the second column into two with in the same statement that I am doing my join?

Comment: @Mr.Doge sure; just use substr to get the first 4 numbers and then again to get the 5th and subsequent numbers. Remember to convert them back to a number once you've split them, if you're using them to join to another numeric column.

Comment: I've edited my answer both with the @Boneist suggestion and OP new requirement.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Dammit, I can't upvote more than once! *{;-)

Comment: @Mr.Doge If the answer helped you and you consider it as the right one, please consider in accepting it so it can help others. Click on the "V" mark on the leftside of the answer.

Comment: I do not have the ability to create a new column in the database I am using so I am trying to do the join with out the creation step. This is the code I am trying to use  
`SELECT a.field, substr(a.field,5) as NEWFEILD FROM table A LEFT OUTER JOIN table b on (TO_NUMBER(substr(a.feild)) = b.feild)` I keep getting an invalid number error. My guess is the TO_number function is not working but I am not sure why.

Comment: It is not working because you are not applying the substr function properly you use: `(TO_NUMBER(substr(a.feild = b.feild` it should be `a.field = to_number(substr(b.field,5))`

Comment: Since `a.field` is already correct and you just need to change the field in table b

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a slightly different approach:

If your column has varchar/char data type:

```
drop table tab1;

drop table tab2;

create table tab1(col char(30));

create table tab2(col char(30));

insert into tab1
select lpad(to_char(level), 6, '0') as val
from dual connect by level <=100 order by level;

insert into tab2
select '2222' || lpad(to_char(level), 6, '0') as val
from dual connect by level <=100 order by level;

create unique index ux_tab1 on tab1(col);

create unique index ux_tab2 on tab2(col);

select tab1.col, tab2.col
from tab1
join tab2
  on '2222' || tab1.col = tab2.col;

-- check execution plan
explain plan for
select tab1.col, tab2.col
from tab1
join tab2
  on '2222' || tab1.col = tab2.col;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

If your column has number data type:

```
drop table tab1;

drop table tab2;

create table tab1(col number);

create table tab2(col number);

insert into tab1
select 100000 + level as val
from dual connect by level <=100 order by level;

insert into tab2
select 2222100000 + level as val
from dual connect by level <=100 order by level;

create unique index ux_tab1 on tab1(col);

create unique index ux_tab2 on tab2(col);

select tab1.col, tab2.col
from tab1
join tab2
  on 2222000000 + tab1.col = tab2.col;


-- check execution plan
explain plan for
select tab1.col, tab2.col
from tab1
join tab2
  on 2222000000 + tab1.col = tab2.col;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

**Using this approach Oracle will be able to use indexes for joining !**

Comment: I tried using the code you wrote for the string. The query ran but returned no results. but table fields are char data types. Also what is the functionality of the '||'?

Comment: @Mr.Doge, || - is a string concatenation operator in Oracle - it concatenates strings.
I have updated my answer with the working example.